# build of MobileVLC for iOS fails

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, terminal, vlc

I'm trying to compile VLC player for iOS.

I've cloned git from repo, a tried to run "buildMobileVLC.sh" (using [this wiki documentation](http://wiki.videolan.org/MobileVLC#Source_Code))

```
$ git clone git://git.videolan.org/MobileVLC.git
$ cd MobileVLC
$ ./buildMobileVLC.sh
```

But as the result I have in terminal next:

```
SDKROOT not specified, assuming /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk
*** /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk does not exist, please install required SDK, or set SDKROOT manually. ***
```

Even this

```
./buildMobileVLC.sh -k iphoneos5.0
```

can't help to solve the problem

P.S.  When I try:

```
./buildMobileVLC.sh -h
```

It says

```
   -k       Specify which sdk to use (see 'xcodebuild -showsdks', current: iphoneos5.0)
```

What am I doing wrong? And should I install iPhone SDK 5.1, if "yes", then how?

**UPD:**
I changed

```
SDK_VERSION=5.0
```

in file "build.sh" in /Users//MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/extras/package/ios

The error disappeared but the new error in Terminal is:

```
./libavutil/arm/asm.S:180:cannot use register index with PC-relative addressing -- `ldr r4,[pc,r4]'
./libavutil/arm/asm.S:180:cannot use register index with PC-relative addressing -- `ldr lr,[pc,lr]'
clang: error: assembler command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [libavcodec/arm/ac3dsp_armv6.o] Error 1
make: *** [.ffmpeg] Error 2
```

Comment: Compiling VLC for iOS is such a pain ... Be brave ^^

Comment: "Art has graffitti software engineering has open source software" :P

Comment: @Pierre, Thank you, but it would be nice if you help me to solve this issue))

Comment: I know. I tried lot of time without success :'(

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should install the iOS SDK, you can get it by installing Xcode from the Appstore.

Error is telling you that the SDK can not be found, after you install Xcode the SDK will be installed.

With the new Xcode the SDK is in the Xcode bundle, `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`
As suggest you could set the `SDKROOT` to this path if it can't find the SDK.

---

It appears that the mobile build for VLC is broken: http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=103322

Comment: How do you mean "is not a clue"?

Comment: Why not,you are missing the iOS SDK and you can only install it by installing Xcode.